# Monster Mash shortcuts

Tags: image, 3d, 2d

Monster Mash is located here (https://github.com/google/monster-mash): what is keyboard shortcut to save the obj file? Ctrl+s only gives a message "Saving project to a zip file". There is no actual file saved.

Compiling the web version is successful but when opened in a browser does not render properly with the downloading prompt running forever.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

I have compiled both the versions (web and desktop). Web version does not render properly in any browser whereas the desktop version runs fine but I could not get it to save the project.